# Show or hide individual subsites using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to show or hide subsite link from Parent site top navigation.
e.g. from UI i can do it by

- Show or hide individual sub sites and pages

  - On the Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.
  - On the Site Actions menu, point to Site Settings, and then click Modify All Site Settings.
  - In the Look and Feel column, click Navigation.
  - In the Navigation Editing and Sorting section, select the sub site or page you want and do one of the following:
  - If you want to show a page or subsite that is hidden, select the item, and then click Show.
  - If you want to hide a page or subsite that is currently visible, select the item, and then click Hide.

Now i want to hide/show specific subsite using PowerShell. I little know PowerShell. Is there any example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide a subsite with the following script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-SPWeb http://SubSiteUrl...
$publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$publishingWeb.IncludeInGlobalNavigation = $false
$publishingWeb.Update();
$web.Dispose()
```

To delete a heading or a link use this script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

$rootWeb = Get-SPWeb http://rootWebUrl...
$rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
$topNavLink = $web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar[index] #index of the link you want to delete
$topNavLink.Delete()
$rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to this one myself:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/site/web
 $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb ($web)
 Global Showsubsites and pages:
 $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = $true
 $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = $true

Current Showsubsites and pages:
$pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = $true
$pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = $true

Don't forget update:

$pubWeb.Update()
$web.Dispose()

Done!
```

More info here:
http://get-spscripts.com/2011/04/managing-quick-launch-current.html